# Will the last derivative of every differentiable function be a constant?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

The $ nth $ derivative of a function tells the rate of change of the $ (n-1)th $ derivative of a function, and if $n=1$, we'll get the first derivative of our function.

So consider a function 
 $y = x^2$  
 $\implies$ $\frac {d(x^2)}{dx} = 2x$
 This means that the slope of the tangent line at any $x$ value of the graph is $2x$.

But what happens when we further differentiate our first derivative?

 We have $\frac{d(2x)}{dx} = 2 $

So if we plot $y'(x)$ on the graph, we get to know that the slope of $y'(x)$ at any $x$ value is 2. This means that the graph of $y'(x)$ is a straight line. So my question is :

> Is it true that every differentiable function's last derivative expression, when plotted, will be a straight line?

Or in other words, can every differentiable function be differentiated till we get a constant?

EDIT : Every differentiable function can be differentiated infinitely many times, and the derivative of $0$ is $0$. I thought that $0$ couldn't be differentiated further.

Comment: What do you mean by "last derivative"? There is no "last derivative" for $x^2$, it is differentiable infinitely many times.

Comment: @Zachary Selk. After differentiating 2, we get 0. How can we further differentiate 0?

Comment: The derivative of $0$ is just $0$

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the help. So this means that after we have reached 0, we will continue to get 0 thereafter?

Comment: Yes, that is true

Comment: But what is the physical interpretation of differentiating 0 and obtaining 0 thereafter?

Comment: The function $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ represents a horizontal line at $y=0$. Its slope is $0$.

Comment: For example, trying this with $f(x)=x^{3/2}$ fails.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. Appreciate your courtesy.

Comment: Another example is $f(x) = \sin x$. It's derivative is $\cos x$ and second derivative is $-\sin x$ and you can go on forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = e^x$. Every derivative of $f$ is also $e^x$, so it will never become constant. In fact, almost all functions have the property that no amount of differentiating will produce a constant.

It is true, however, that for any polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $n$, the $n$th derivative of $g$ is constant (and so the $n+1$-st derivative is the zero function).